# Como passar informações no bindvalue com duas ou mais informações armazenadas na variavel?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

Estou com um problema... Estou pegando alguns id no banco de dados e armazenando na `$ids_cozinha`. dei um `var_dump` e um `print_r`, está me retornando os id que eu quero, até ai tudo bem.

```
<pre>
<?php print_r(implode(", ",$ids_cozinha))?>
</pre>
```

Tenho esse resultado.

> 20, 21

Tenho uma query no `php prepare("SELECT XXXXX")` que preciso inserir esses ids (21 e 21) que foi armazenado na $ids_cozinha, porém no bindValue não está aceitando mais do que um id vindo da variável `$ids_cozinha`, justamente porque ele é um array.

Está assim..

```
$sql->bindValue(":ids_cozinha", implode(", ",$ids_cozinha));
```

Mesmo assim não estão aceitando os ids.
Está encontrando somente o primeiro ID que é o 20.

Como posso passar esses ids que estão armazenando nessa `$ids_cozinha`?

PS: Executando a query diretamente no banco de dados, estão retornando com exatidão todas informações que preciso.

Comment: Bem vindo Rafael, seria possível postar o código inteiro, está meio difícil de entender por estes fragmentos...

Comment: Olá Alvaro, obrigado por ajudar, se eu postar o código inteiro pode acabar se confundindo ainda mais, tendo em vista que minha query é um pouco grande, pois faço LEFT JOIN em diversas tabelas para inserir o resultado no :ids_cozinha.

Acima desse codigo eu faço um outro select e armazeno esses ids (array) em uma $variavel.

Então faço isso.

  $ids_cozinha = $variavel

Como expliquei anteriormente, dei um var_dump e um print_r para verificar se realmente estava recebendo esses array de id, e observei que estavam sim, recebeu 20,21, eu so quero passar esses valores para o bindValue

Answer (score 0):

Estava passando por uma situação similar a dessa pergunta.
Estava querendo pegar os e-mails dos usuários com os ids que constavam naquele '**$array**'.

**Resolvi da forma abaixo:**

```
$array = [1,5,9];
$ids = implode(',',$array);
                           
 $conn = new Conexao();
 $conexao = $conn->conectar();
                                            
 $query = "SELECT email FROM usuarios WHERE id IN(".$ids.")";
                            
 $stmt = $conexao->prepare($query);                           
 $stmt->execute();                            
 $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

**Tem também a forma alternativa abaixo (que me recomendaram e disseram ser melhor):**

```
 $conn = new Conexao();
 $conexao = $conn->conectar();

 $array = [1,5,9];
 $param = rtrim(str_repeat('?,', count($array)),',');
                                            
 $query = "SELECT email FROM usuarios WHERE id IN(".$param.")";
                            
 $stmt = $conexao->prepare($query);                           
 $stmt->execute($array); 

 $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Dessa forma acima os valores não são passados diretamente para a query.